# How can I create a Json files which will group together with 1 parent class & 2 multiple child classes in Entity Framework C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am creating an API which call to get the data via the Entity Framework Core 6.

Basically, have the following classes:

For parent class, let's say I have the following.

```
public class Student
{
    public string student_ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string GradeID { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Address> address { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Grade> grade { get; set; }
}
```

And the first child class, I have the class name address, with the same student ID.  So I will use Icollection to join these two classes (Student and Address).

```
public class Address
{
    public string student_ID { get; set; }
    public int Seq { get; set; }    
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public Student student { get; set; }
}
```

For the Grade, Let's say I have an ID & SubjectID as a primary key, and I want to join the parent class with SubjectID (Where grade ID is not a primary key in the Student class).  I tried with the following setup on the following class:

```
public class Subject
{
    public int SubjectID{ get; set; }
    public int GradeID{ get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public Student student { get; set; }
}
```

How can I make the API result to JSON to be the following:

```
[
 {
   "student_ID": "001"
   "Name": "Jason"
   "GradeID": [
              {
               "SugjectID": "S01"
               "GradeID": "Grade_6"
               "Description": "English"
              },
              {
               "student_ID": "001"
               "GradeID": "Grade_6"
               "Description": "Math"
              }
             ],
   "Address": [
              {
               "student_ID": "001"
               "Seq": "1"
               "Address": "123 Apple Street"
              },
              {
               "SubjectID": "001"
               "Seq": "2"
               "Address": "123 Orange Road"
              }
             ]
 }
]
```

I tried to not doing any relationship mapping in between Student & Subject, by doing join in API with the following:

```
var result = dbcontext.studnet.Include(x => x.Address).where( x => x.student_ID == strStudentID).Join(dbcontext.Subject, x => x.Student_ID, y => y.Student_ID, (x, y) => new {x, y});

return OK(result);
```

But it give me the following result which is duplicate:

```
[
 {
   "student_ID": "001"
   "Name": "Jason"
   "GradeID": [
              {
               "SugjectID": "S01"
               "GradeID": "Grade_6"
               "Description": "English"
              },
              {
               "student_ID": "001"
               "GradeID": "Grade_6"
               "Description": "Math"
              }
             ],
   "Address": [
              {
               "student_ID": "001"
               "Seq": "1"
               "Address": "123 Apple Street"
              }
             ]
 },
 {
   "student_ID": "001"
   "Name": "Jason"
   "GradeID": [
              {
               "SugjectID": "S01"
               "GradeID": "Grade_6"
               "Description": "English"
              },
              {
               "student_ID": "001"
               "GradeID": "Grade_6"
               "Description": "Math"
              }
             ],
   "Address": [
              {
               "SubjectID": "001"
               "Seq": "2"
               "Address": "123 Orange Road"
              }
             ]
 }
]
```

I tried so many methods, but could not find a solution. What can I try next?

Comment: I couldn't figure out, but I ended up create two views in the database, and create two classes to apply this.

It gives me the same result as what I expected.  

Thank you!

Comment: Why not go with multiple includes?